# DataNucleus libraries and maven-gae-plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus, maven-gae-plugin

I'm using maven-gae-plugin to manage a Google AppEngine project but I don't know how to include the libraries required to use JPA.

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview) says:

> The classpath must contain the JARs 'datanucleus-core-*.jar', 'datanucleus-jpa-*', 'datanucleus-enhancer-*.jar', 'asm-*.jar', and 'geronimo-jpa-*.jar' (where * is the appropriate version number of each JAR) from the 'appengine-java-sdk/lib/tools/' directory, as well as all of your data classes.

How can I tell the plugin to put all the jars in the classpath?

So far I just edited the `pom.xml` file setting `gae.version` to `1.7.3` (Leaving `datanucleus.version` to `1.1.5` and I run `mvn gae:unpack` but I cannot get it to work.

First, I have problems with `javax.persistance` that is not found. Do I have to add it manually to `pom.xml`?

If I do it, the development server starts, but I cannot work with the storage: I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Found Meta-Data for class com.sharecost.entities.User but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the second part of my question. Looking at the `POM.xml` file I discovered that the all entities are supposed to be in a `**/model` package.

I still don't know if the manual inclusion of the `javax.persistence` dependency is actually required.